# Cannot run the controller

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to do a simple app with ionic framework to learn how to use Firebase and manipulate data. I did everything, but my console is showing nothing. I cannot run my controller. Does anyone know what is happening?

I injected everything, at least I think I did. I guess the error is in the resolve. Is there anyone that can save me with this, please?

Here's my Controller:

```js
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('hsAdmin.users')
        .controller('UsersCtrl', UsersCtrl);

    UsersCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$state','Users' ];

    function UsersCtrl($scope, $state,Users ){
        var vm = angular.extend(this, {
            ChangeState: ChangeState,
            Users:Users
        });


        function ChangeState(state){
            $state.go(state);
        }
    }    
})();
```

Here's my Module:

```js
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('hsAdmin.users', [
            'ionic',
            'ngCordova',
            'hsAdmin.users'
        ])
        .config(function($stateProvider) {
        
        $stateProvider
            .state('app.users', {
                url: '/users',
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/users/users.html',
                        controller: 'UsersCtrl as vm'
                    }
                }
                ,resolve:{
                    Users: function(UsersService) {
                        return UsersService.GetUsers().$loaded().then(function(user){
                            return user;
                        }).catch(function(error){
                             console.log('Error when get users: ' + error);
                        })
                    }
                }
            });
        })  
})();
```

Here's my Service

```js
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('hsAdmin.users')
        .factory('UsersService', UsersService);

    UsersService.$inject = ['fb', '$firebaseArray', '$firebaseObject','$q','$rootScope'];

    function UsersService(fb, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject,$q,$rootScope){
        var service = {
            GetUsers:GetUsers,
            GetUsersById:GetUsersById
        };
        return service;

        function GetUsers(){
            var query = fb.child('/users');
            return $firebaseArray(query);
        }

        function GetUsersById(id){
            var query = fb.child('/users/' + id);
            return $firebaseObject(query).$loaded();
        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your `hsAdmin.users` module and then injecting it into itself, that is likely what is causing your problem. Try the below:

```js
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('hsAdmin.users', [
            'ionic',
            'ngCordova',
            // 'hsAdmin.users'
        ])
        .config(function($stateProvider) {
        
        $stateProvider
            .state('app.users', {
                url: '/users',
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/users/users.html',
                        controller: 'UsersCtrl as vm'
                    }
                }
                ,resolve:{
                    Users: function(UsersService) {
                        return UsersService.GetUsers().$loaded().then(function(user){
                            return user;
                        }).catch(function(error){
                             console.log('Error when get users: ' + error);
                        })
                    }
                }
            });
        })  
})();
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem remain :/

Comment: @LucasGaspar Is there any error message in the JS console?

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement controller in following way.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var UsersCtrl = function($scope, $state, Users) {

    var vm = angular.extend(this, {
      ChangeState: ChangeState,
      Users: Users
    });


    function ChangeState(state) {
      $state.go(state);
    }
  }

  UsersCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'Users'];

  angular.module('hsAdmin.users').controller('UsersCtrl', UsersCtrl);

})();
```